# How to dynamically turn a text field into dropdown?

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-browser

The name says all. I want to change a text field element into combo box using javascript. It will be nice if it's cross-browser.

EDIT: I may use jQuery

Comment: Interesting. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do this in Lynx or good 'ole "telnet to port 80"... or NCSA Mosaic or Netscape 1.x...

Comment: Why not use jQuery? I've never heard of NOT using jQuery as a requirement

Comment: @Felix Kling: I tried: document.getElementById('myElement').type = 'select-one'; on <input type="hidden" name="myElement" id="myElement" value="some text" />

Comment: `select-one` is not even a valid value for `type`.

Comment: @Felix Kling: That's what js returned of type for: <select name="persons" id="persons" style="width: 40px;"> That's why I used it.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to create the dropdown element and add it to the form, as well as remove the text field.  You can have HTML like this:

```
<form id='myform'>
    ...
    <span id='textelement'>text goes here</span>
    <input type='button' value='change text to dropdown' onclick='change()'/>
    ...
</form>
```

Then your `change()` function could be something like this:

```
function change() {
    var _form = document.getElementById('myform');
    var _text = document.getElementById('textelement');
    _form.removeChild(_text);

    var _combo = document.createElement('select');
    _combo.setAttribute('size', '1');
    _combo.setAttribute('id', 'dropdownelement');
    _form.appendChild(_combo);
    _combo = document.getElementById('dropdownelement');

    //add first value to the dropdown
    var _opt = document.createElement('option');
    _opt.text = 'New option 1';
    _opt.value = '1';
    _combo.add(_opt);
    //add second value to the dropdown
    _opt = document.createElement('option');
    _opt.text = 'New option 2';
    _opt.value = '2';
    _combo.add(_opt);
    ...
}
```

Note that I haven't tested this code - use it as a starting point only.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to change it client side or server side. If client side there really is not way without using javascript of some sort.

Comment: OP wants to use Javascript, but not jQuery.

Comment: He only said he does not want to use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use InnerHTML but it isn't compatible with all browsers (Not compatible with: NN4 , OP5, OP6)